# get record count for each year in database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two mysql database tables: people and markers
They join on MarkerID (people.MarkerID = markers.MarkerID)

The markers table has these fields:

```
MarkerID
lat
lng
date
```

The people table has these fields

```
peopleID
MarkerID
```

There can be many people to one marker.

What I want is to get the total number of people records for each year, preferably in one query. How would I do that?

I need to get the count of people for each distinct year(markers.date), so there needs to be a group by and left join, I think. I did it this way, but the counts are sometimes a little off. Am I counting markers or people here?

```
    Select year(m.date), Count(*)
From markers As m
    Join people As p
        On p.MarkerID = m.MarkerID
Group By year(m.date)
```

Comment: Provide some sample data , and expected result, this would make easier to debug the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are joining on `MarkerID` but want the count of distinct people so I believe you want :

```
SELECT YEAR(m.date), COUNT(DISTINCT peopleID)
FROM markers AS m
JOIN people AS p USING(MarkerID)
GROUP BY YEAR(m.date)
```

Comment: Makes sense plus neat `using` – nice.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what issue you are running into, but you can potentially start out with a subselect.

Have one query that gets all the records that you are interested in, then from those results do your count on it.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), year 
FROM
 (SELECT year(m.date) year 
  FROM markers as m 
  JOIN people as p 
  ON p.MarkerID = m.MarkerID)
GROUP BY year
```

Comment: A little elaboration?